# /usr/bin/python: No module named barista.__main__; 'barista' is a package and cannot be directly executed

Tags: python, python-2.7, caffe, pycaffe

I am trying to drive github project: https://github.com/kjchavez/distributed-deep-q with Ubuntu16.04 python2.7.12. I have installed caffe and pycaffe correctly.

When i am trying to make a new caffemodel as with command below (given in readme)

> python -m barista models/deepq/train_val.prototxt models/deepq/deepq.caffemodel --solver models/deepq/solver.prototxt

it gives me error

> /usr/bin/python: No module named barista.__main __; 'barista' is a package and cannot be directly executed

I have read about same kind of errors in python2.6 with command "python -m" but im using python 2.7. Barista is a directory inside of the main project directory and it consist python files with __init __.py but not __main __.py. I have included to $PYTHONPATH in .bashrc file paths /caffe/python and /main_project_directory.

If someone have an idea where I fail I would be very happy. I think that problem is in python version but not sure about that. I can give extra information about my systems and setups in later posts.

Answer (score 2):

The [readme](https://github.com/kjchavez/distributed-deep-q/blob/54e095b/README.md) says you're supposed to use something like this to start the program:

```
python main.py models/deepq/train_val.prototxt models/deepq/deepq16.caffemodel
```

It seems that at some point there was a file `[...]/barista/__main__.py` which would allow to use `python -m barista`, but that file [has been renamed](https://github.com/kjchavez/distributed-deep-q/commit/b0acfaac55b50eba931d4fcf9bdf96ce9230f901) to `[...]/main.py`, the description [here](https://github.com/kjchavez/distributed-deep-q/blob/5e496e7/barista/README.md) probably just wasn't updated.